# Can we change global variables value from a function and toggle it's value based on local variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have declared a variable having global scope and want to change it's value dynamically from a function in which i have same variable and want that variable to reflect change in global variable based on local variable. But still I am not able to change value of global variable's
value.
Can anyone suggest me how can we reflect global variable's value based on local variable's value ?

```
    export default {
      data() {
        return { 
          status: false //global variable
        };
      },
      methods: {
        state(state) { //here i am receiving a value as true or false 
          this.status = state.value; // and i can see that when i check that on  
          return status; //console but still this doesn't reflect global one
       }
      }
```

Comment: How do you see that the status variable doesn't change ?

Comment: @F_Mekk by vue dev tools it's visible that status variable is false and is not changing

Comment: and where did you call this method ?

Comment: Have you tried returning this.status?

Comment: @LassiUosukainen yes i tried and that did the magic!! thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code

```js
    export default {
      data() {
        return { 
          status: false //global variable
        };
      },
      methods: {
        state(state) { 
          this.status = state.value; 
          return this.status; // <-- this.status - that was the mistake
       }
      }
```